# Schemas and Maps for Azure LogicApps in VS 2019

Tags: visual-studio, xslt, schema, biztalk, azure-logic-apps

I used Enterprise Integration Pack in Visual Studio 2015 to create schemas and maps for Azure Logic Apps integration accounts.

Recently I upgraded my environment to VS 2019. I cannot migrate my projects from VS 2015 and cannot find any work around to load my projects into VS 2019. I'd like to have similar functionality so my end users can create schemas and maps by themselves via GUI interface.

Does it mean VS 2019 drop these features? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Product Group is planning to have this in this semester but this timeline is subject to change. In a meanwhile do consider VS2015.

Comment: Thank you very much!